# FactoryBot #build object with an associated object passed in not properly creating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a Rails app with two models, call them `transaction` and `item`.  Transactions are created during a checkout flow, and have an associated `item` object, the `transaction` holds the details of a sale, and `item` represents the item being sold.

Models are setup like so:

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item

  validates :item_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord 
  has_one :company_transaction, class_name: 'Transaction'
end
```

And the factories are setup like so:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :transaction do
    item { build_stubbed(:item) }
    # Other transaction related attributes
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    # Item related attributes
  end
end
```

Now, if I create a `Transaction` object using simple `transaction = build(:transaction)` I get the transaction, and it works as expected, with an `Item` object also being created and accessible:

```
transaction.item_id => #####
transaction.item => #<Item:0x00007fcb08fab628...>
transaction.valid? => true
```

But, if I create an `Item` object first, and pass it into the `Transaction` factory, it exists, sort of, but not as it does with above.  If I run something like:

```
item = build(:item)
transaction = build(:transaction, item: item)
```

I get

```
transaction.item_id => nil
transaction.item => #<Item:0x00007fcb08fab628...>
transaction.valid? => false
```

The `Transaction` object is no longer valid because the `item_id` field is `nil` and this causes test to fail.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  If I use `create` on the two classes the items are properly built and saved to the database, and the proper fields are updated, but using `build` this fails.  I don't understand why I could get a proper, "full" association using `build` and allowing the `Transaction` factory to build it's own `Item` object, yet if I build my own `Item` object and pass it in the association is created (as evidenced by `transaction.item` working) but the associated field is blank, and causing failed validation checks.

Comment: why do you need to use `build_stubbed`? I think it relates to build strategy

Answer (score 2):

After typing all this out, I realized that I could use `build_stubbed` to create a new instance of the `Item` class like `item = build_stubbed(:item)`.  Passing that into the `Transaction` factory like `transaction = build(:transaction, item: item)` is creating the properly working association, and adding a value to `transaction.item_id`.  What I still don't understand is why this is the case, if anyone could enlighten me I'd greatly appreciate it.